# I accidentally deleted an instance GoogleConsoleCloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-console-developer

I accidentally deleted an instance, instead of clicking "stop" clicked "delete" BECAUSE IT IS SET 2 centimeters FROM YOURSELF.. What's the point?
I need to find TRANSLATIONS, not "talk" - how to restore my instance, because I had very important files there. I read something about object versioning - but it doesn't work. Please explain to me what to do.. eh
I've lost COMPUTE ENGINE instance - not cloudSQL

Comment: For future use, you can consider [machine images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images/create-machine-images) , [persistent disk snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots), and [custom images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#custom_images) as a backup process for your vm to secure your data.

Answer (score 1):

follow the steps as provided in the official google cloud documentation for restoring an instance:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring

you can only restore to a backup, if you dont have one. Then im sorry but there is nothing you can do

for future ref, (you said its a Compute engine instance) refer to this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion

however right now, there is nothing you can do its gone

Comment: It's not a SQL instance - it's Compute Engine Instance, i've lost my all data..

Answer (score 0):

Generally, snapshots are used to backup data from your [persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) and you can create an instance from your snapshot by following the instructions on this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot).

Therefore, unfortunately if there are no snapshots taken already from the VM’s disk(s), the deleted VM instance cannot be recovered.

At this point, if you wish a recovery option to get implemented in the future, as described in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/dr-scenarios-planning-guide#application_backup_and_recovery), you can use GCE snapshots to create diff-based backups of persistent disks attached to the instance, including boot volumes. This is useful for backing up your data, recreating a disk that might have been lost, or copying a persistent disk. That being said, currently this is the method you can recover deleted instances.